# find array element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array

```
@words = Word.find_all_by_lesson_id(params[:id]) - @user.words
```

and want to find one element by word_id, something like

```
@current_word = @words[params[:id2].to_i]
```

where
`params[:id2]` is `words.id`

Of course it's wrong, because the arrays index is not the same as `words.id`, 
so how can I do it correct?

OR

can you advice me on how to work with the model if I want to exclude some records from it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
@current_word = @words.detect{|w| w.id == params[:id2]}
```